# When to use .length vs .length()

Tags: java, arrays

Ok so I have this code:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] people = {"Bob", "Billy", "Jim"};
        int sum = 0;

        for(int i = 0; i < people.length; i++) {
            sum += people[i].length();
        }
    }
}
```

My question is why `people[i].length()` is `.length()` and not `.length`. I thought to get the length of an array you use `.length` and not `.length()`. Do you use `.length()` because you are trying to get the length of a string and not an array? P.S. I am a beginner, so this may seem very obvious to you, but it isn't to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

They're two completely different things.

`.length` is a property on **arrays**.  That isn't a method call.

`.length()` is a method call on `String`.

You're seeing both because first, you're iterating over the length of the array.  The contents of the array are `String`, and you want to add up all of their lengths, so you then call the length on each individual `String` in the array.

Comment: Using the word "objects" here is potentially confusing for a beginner, I think. Perhaps "different things"?

Comment: Well, an array is *technically* an object...but you may have a point.

Answer (score 3):

`.length` is an array property. `.length()` is a method for the class `String` ([look here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29)).

When you are looping, you are looping for the length of the array using `people.length`.

But when you are using `people[i].length()`, you are accessing the string at that position of the array, and getting the length of the string, therefore using the `.length()` *method* in the `String` class.

However, just to confuse you more, a `String` at its core is just an array of `char`s (like this: `char[]`). One could make the argument that `.length` should work as well, considering it is an array of characters, however, it is a *class* and that is the reason `.length` will not work. Showing empty parameters shows it's a method, and showing no parameters shows that it's a property (like a `static` variable in a class).

Answer (score 2):

`.length` is for Arrays, and `.length()` for Strings

Array's length is a field, while the String's length is in a function - `.length()`