# How to create and return a enum in a method in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, enums

I have a method that should return a enum, however I am not to sure how to code this (it is a activity from my paper). Below is the method (in the class called Maze):

```java
private MazeStatus[][] stringToMaze(String sMaze) {
    String[] splitString = sMaze.split("\n");
    char[][] array = new char[splitString.length][];
    MazeStatus[][] mazeStat;

    for (int x = 0; x < splitString.length; x++) {
        array[x] = new char[splitString[x].length()];
        array[x] = splitString[x].toCharArray();
        for (int y = 0; y < splitString[x].length(); y++) {
            switch (array[x][y]) {
                case '.':
                    mazeStat[x][y] = MazeStatus.VISITED;
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
    return null; // TO DO (Part 1): change appropriately
}
```

Here is the `MazeStatus` class:

```java
public enum MazeStatus {
    OPEN(' '), OBSTACLE('#'), GOAL('x'), VISITED('.');

    private char text;

    MazeStatus(char s) {
        this.text = s;
    }

    public char text() {
        return this.text;
    }
}
```

In the method I have tried creating a enum

```
MazeStatus[][] mazeStat;
```

and adding values to it:

```
mazeStat[x][y] = MazeStatus.VISITED;
```

But of course it complains about it not being initialized. I do not know how to initialize a enum, especially a bidimensional array enum, without creating the actual Maze object.

Comment: `mazeStat` is not an enum, it is a 2D object array, and needs to be initialized the same way all other 2D arrays are initialized, i.e. using `new MazeStatus[...][...]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the size of your 2D array, like this:

```
MazeStatus[][] mazeStat = new MazeStatus[row.length][column.length];
```

I don't know exactly what the size will be in your case, that's why I've used `row.length` and `column.length`. But please replace these with values that make sense in your code.

Comment: Thank you, this does answer my question! Just so used to ussing ArrayList now a days so forgot about having to initialize all arrays. However I do now run into a issue. The user can input a String that represents a maze and what I am doing is converting that String into a MazeStatus[][] array. So I can set the first part by doing MazeStatus[splitString[x].length()] but I am not sure what to put in the second [] as each line can be a different size. Could have 5 columns but each row is a different size so not sure how to initialize it in that case.  Sorry still new to 2d arrays!

Comment: Well, you could ask the user to input the maze size at first? And then use these parameters to initialize your 2D array. Otherwise, you could replace the 2D array with a `List<List<MazeStatus> mazeStat = new ArrayList<>()`, and use the `List` API to build your maze. Then, when returning, just convert from 2D List to 2D Array.

Comment: Just checked and turns out all inputted mazes will always have the same size, as in all rows will be the same size! So I will just get the first rows length and use it to initialize the second part of the array! I am having a issue doing so though. When I do MazeStatus[][] mazeStat = new MazeStatus[splitString.length][array[0].length()]; the compiler says "cannot find symbol" and points at the dot after array[0]?

Comment: `length` is a property on the array, not a function. I think it should be `array[0].length`.

Comment: That has worked, thank you once again. Could you explain why for the char 2d array I have to do .length without () yet with String 2d array I have to do .length() please?

Comment: This should answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23396421/when-to-use-length-vs-length. Or even more complex answer, this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23730092/how-can-i-get-the-size-of-an-array-a-collection-or-a-string-in-java

Answer (score 0):

```java
private MazeStatus[][] stringToMaze(String sMaze) {
    String[] splitString = sMaze.split("\n");
    char[][] array = new char[splitString.length][];

    //this is missing in your code ........
    MazeStatus[][] mazeStat = new MazeStatus[splitString.length][column.length];
    for (int x = 0; x < splitString.length; x++) {
        array[x] = new char[splitString[x].length()];
        array[x] = splitString[x].toCharArray();
        for (int y = 0; y < splitString[x].length(); y++) {
            switch (array[x][y]) {
                case '.':
                    System.out.println("x" + x + " y" + y);
                    mazeStat[x][y] = MazeStatus.VISITED;
                    break;
                default:
                    mazeStat[x][y] = MazeStatus.OPEN;
                    /*
                     *this you have to put accordingly because if default 
                     *condition won't be there then it will take null
                     *values and it will throw NullPointerException
                     */
            }
        }
    }
    return mazeStat; // TO DO (Part 1): change appropriately
}
```